# Why does the else part auto trigger on the second loop in my program?

Tags: c

I have a block of code like the following :

```c
char option;

while (1) {
    option = -1;
    option = getch();

    if(option == 13){
    //do something
    }

    else{
    //do something
    }

}
```

On the second loop, the else part auto triggers, even if I press enter(13), for some reason and hence I'm unable to understand why this is happening?

Comment: You could print out the decimal code for the character, so you can verify if it is what you think it should be. Add a `printf("Read character code %d\n", option);` after your call to `getch()`

Comment: What is the input? Please provide a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example (https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: If you press ENTER, you probably get 'linefeed' character, i.e. code 10. On Windows you get `return` followed by `linefeed`.

Comment: Setting *option* to -1 just before resetting it makes no sense.

Comment: The input I'm providing is just Enter Key. It triggers the option == 13 block once(checked that using the printf command), next it goes to the else block(and now the printf output is 0 for option, even though I pressed enter only once, it looped 2 times)

Comment: I suspect your system is generating CRLF line breaks, so the carriage return (`\r`) is immediately followed by a new line (`\n`). As @nos suggested, printing out the value returned from `getch()` will show you what is happening. Also, since `getch()` returns an `int`, it's probably a bad idea to stuff the return value into a `char` variable.

Comment: The first input in int is 13 as expected. The second automatic input without me doing anything is 0 in int format. And this is triggering the else statement.

Comment: Add a breakpoint inside `if` and `else`, what is the value of `option` when you press the enter key?. 

I am supposing that you know that the `else` condition will be executed as many times as possible, however the `if` condition will be executed once time per enter key pressed.

Comment: Most keyboards have 2 different keys for Enter, one on the normal alpha pad (often tagged *Return*) and one on the numeric keypad. Do both keys have same behaviour? And what happens if you change `option` to be an `int` (what it really should be...)

Comment: So here is what I found out using the debugger and using breakpoints. the value of option remains 13 till the getch function is read the second time. This time it doesn't ask for any value and automatically assumes the value 0 and proceeds. Still no clue why this happens! Even in the line before getch, the value of option was 13, and magically it assumes the value 0. What's even more funny is that, in the second iteration, option is not set to -1 as well, which is weird!

Comment: My guess is that your problem stems from something in code you have not shown.   Can you post an actual code snippet that has everything in it?

Comment: @TotalAnimeImmersion That is weird indeed, and it indicates that the issue is somewhere in the code that you have not posted here, or is related to your environment (your OS,compiler, manner in which you compile and run the program etc.). You should reduce your code to the smallest possible that produces your issue, and post all that code so someone here can compile and run it, just like you do.

Comment: The option is not set to -1 because the compiler knows it will be set to the result of getch() and nothing can access the variable between `option = -1` and getch() returning. It is therefore optimized away.

Comment: Which `getch` function are you using? Windows has a `getch` function that reads a character (apparently it's deprecated). The curses/ncurses package (mostly used on Unix-like systems) has a different function of the same name. If you update your question to show a [mcve] (read the linked article), the `#include` headers should make it clear which one you're using. Without a complete example, it may not be possible to answer your question.

Answer (score 1):

Essencially the getch function only reads the first thing you press in your keyboard or already is in the buffer. So, if you try to type 13, the getch function will only read the '1'.